# Main Menu disappear in e4 eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I am developing a mixed rcp application.
with the following tutorial I am able to open Pydev Perspective using 3.x commands

[Eclipse rcp e4 with 3.x views, etc](https://dirksmetric.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/tutorial-eclipse-rcp-e4-with-3-x-views-like-project-explorer-properties-etc/)

```
...
OpenPerspective("org.python.pydev.ui.PythonPerspective");
...

public static void OpenPerspective(String idPerspective) 
{
    IPerspectiveDescriptor[] perspectives = 
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry().getPerspectives();
    IPerspectiveDescriptor per = null;
    IWorkbenchPage page = getActivePage();

    for (IPerspectiveDescriptor descriptor : perspectives) {
        if (descriptor.getId().equals(idPerspective)) {
            per = descriptor;
        }
    }

    if (page != null) {
        page.setPerspective(per);
    } else {
    }
}

private static IWorkbenchPage getActivePage() 
{
    IWorkbenchPage result = null;
    IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        result = window.getActivePage();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am having a problem when i add a menu in Application.e4xmi, i ran the product and all is ok. In the second run the main toolbar disappear.

I find that is related with the following bug

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388808

but i can't make work the workaround.

Anybody have a good example, step by step how make work the workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to [add the mentioned](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=220714) `ForceMainMenuProcessor` to the `org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model` - extension point as a processor (with `beforefragment:true` and `apply:always`).

You can do so in your plugin.xml under tab "Extensions":

Hit the "Add..." Button, search for `org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model` and add it with ID=MainAppModel.
[image: plugin xml 1]
Right-click on the extension lets you add a processor.
[image: plugin xml 2]

Provided that you dropped the class `ForceMainMenuProcessor` in package `my.package` of your plugin.

Comment: Hi, that is the problem. how do it i follow the tutorial but i dont know where add the proccesor or create and the place where havo to pint. if you can give an exampole please. Thanks